# One Hot Encoding using Dummies in R

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

Need your help for a specific thing i can't hardly explain.
The following code

```
library(dummies)
columna <- c(1,2,3)
columnb <- c("AR","AT","AF")
columnc <- c("word1", "word2", "word3")
alldata <- data.frame(columna,columnb,columnc)
alldata <- dummy.data.frame(alldata, names=c("columnc"), sep="_")
alldata
```

is giving me

```
  columna columnb columnc_word1 columnc_word2 columnc_word3
1       1      AR             1             0             0
2       2      AT             0             1             0
3       3      AF             0             0             1
```

Imagine now, i have

```
columnc <- c("word1", "word2 word3", "word3 word1")
```

Can please someone explain me how to obtain ?

```
  columna columnb columnc_word1 columnc_word2 columnc_word3
1       1      AR             1             0             0
2       2      AT             0             1             1
3       3      AF             1             0             1
```

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` way:

```
library(tidyverse)
alldata %>% 
        separate_rows(columnc) %>% mutate(count = 1) %>% 
        spread(columnc, count, fill = 0, sep = "_")

#  columna columnb columnc_word1 columnc_word2 columnc_word3
#1       1      AR             1             0             0
#2       2      AT             0             1             1
#3       3      AF             1             0             1
```